# What does it do to create a Partition Switching table? Then how can I fill these tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What does it do to create a Partition Switching table? 
Then how can I fill these tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partition switching table is a normal table. But it must be identical to the table you want to switch into.

With regards as to how do you fill a table? You might need to post more info... how are you filling your other tables? It's just another table. Fill it however you see fit.

The trick is....

once you have your table filled and you want to switch it in against another table you run this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE targettable;
ALTER TABLE sourcetable SWITCH TO targettable;
```

You can also add this though I've never tested it (I will be today as I just found it today, here https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/)

```
TRUNCATE TABLE targettable;
ALTER TABLE sourcetable SWITCH TO targettable
WITH ( WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY 
             (MAX_DURATION = 1 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS)                      
     );
```

This replaces targettable with the data in sourcetable

As always, someone has done all this before you and me and blogged it, and it's only a google away

https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/24/reloading-fact-tables-with-zero-downtime/

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea... It's just a simple means of replacing an empty table with a populated table, without having to drop the empty table and rename the populated table. The only caviat is that both tables MUST have the exact same structure, including any and all indexes.

So, say you have 10 million rows of data and you want to delete 9 million of those rows. Deleting 9 million rows in one pop is likely to blow up your tempdb and your transaction logs. As an alternative, you can to a "SELECT INTO" to put the 1 million rows you want to keep into a new table (minimally logged)... add indexes that match the original table... truncate the original table (minimally logged) and the switch the partitions (minimally logged).